# How do you get past the Driller level on VVVVVV?

Tags: vvvvvv

I recently got the game VVVVVV, special thanks to @badp for pointing me to it) and it is very much addicting.

However, I'm stuck on one level: Driller. Here's what it looks like:
[image: driller-vvvvvv]

You obviously have to get to that checkpoint beyond the set of four spikes. Simple, I thought. Just change gravity once, then change it again when in the air. However, the game doesn't work that way. And I'm stuck.

If I go down the hole in the middle I go into another room:

[image]

**and** if I avoid the spikes in the second room, I end up in another room:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get passed this one level?

Comment: What happens if you fall down the hole in the middle?

Comment: I fall into another level that has spikes, I've updated the question with a screenshot (gosh was it hard to get :D). Continuing down just leads to another room, as you can see in the second screenshot.

Comment: @Studoku ***facepalm*** I just figured it out. I just had go out the opposite way I came in, moving to the right once I got back to Driller room again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you get down to the bottom level, flip back up, through the holes, and land on the other side.

Comment: Found that out myself like 5 minutes after I asked :D I'll mark yours as answer cause I'm lazy and don't want to waste time making a self-answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When you start on driller. Go to the next room: 'Exhaust Chute' (Watch out for spikes) Then, you'll go to the next room: 'Sorrow' And flip back up land on other side.